# apply templates to immediate self node

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've an XML of below format.

```
 <book:para>
                <book:page num="228"/>
                <book:page num="229"/>
Other data
 </book:para>
```

Here I want to `apply-templates` to immediate `page` nodes before the text. I'm currently using the below XSLT for doing this task. This matches only one direct `page` before text.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="./node()[1][self::book:page]" mode="first"/>
```

Please let me know how can I do it for more than one `page`.

Thanks

Comment: just remove the `[1]` in your expression, e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="./node()[self::book:page]" mode="first"/>`

Comment: Your question is not clear, because we don't know what your current context is.

Comment: Hi @JoelM.Lamsen, This worked. Thanks.